# my site breaks up in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am sure you have all heard this all before, but IE8 sucks, the Div's are not lining up correctly in my site:

http://www.relayconcepts.co.za/home/

The problem is i can't find out why it's doing that. This is a Joomla site that I have hijacked and inserted my own `HTML/PHP` in certain places and changed `CSS` to no extent.

The thing is that it works well in firefox, Chrome and even IE9 works all right.

Comment: IE8 sucks and is past EOL. Even the "it has to work on the corporate intranet" is thankfully no longer a valid excuse. You do not need to support IE8 anymore. Target IE10/11, everything else you can safely ignore, unless someone's paying you *a lot* of money to care about.

Comment: lol, no they aren't paying me much for this, the problem is that i live in a 3rd world country and most of my client's clients will be so technologically backwards that they might be using Windows xp and not even know that IE8 sucks.

Comment: if they're on XP, and they're your clients, you can tell them to use Chrome or Firefox because XP is EOL, too.

Comment: You have errors in your HTML. Since different browsers react differently to errors, if you correct them, perhaps some of the problems will go away.

Comment: What is breaking up? (I am using an IE10 browser)

Comment: Just took a look and the codes are not formatted correctly and as @MrLister mentioned, there are errors.